# assembly in deployed asp.net application is referencing an absolute path on my pc

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, reference, nullreferenceexception

I do not know why this is happening:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DataWeb.Core.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext Context) in X:\projects\visualstudio\work_projects\Production\DataWeb\DataWeb.Core\HttpHandler.cs:23
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the error message. The path (X:\projects...) is just as an information where the file was stored when it was compiled. It is not referencing anything from there, it just helps you to find the location where the error occurs (in HttpHandler.cs, line 23).